# get count from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with a common 'type_id' column. its a foreign key from Table_type

**Table_1** id,type_id,date...
**Table_2** id,type_id,date...
**Table_3** id,type_id,date...

**Table_Type**  id, type_name, description

> select type_id, count(*) from Table_1 GROUP BY type_id

gives the count from individual table.

i want to know how many times is a particular type used.

```
type_id, count(from 3 tables)
1      , 10
2      , 5
3 .    , 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the counts from each table, combine those queries with `UNION`, and add up the counts.

```
SELECT type_id, SUM(count)
FROM (
    SELECT type_id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT type_id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM table_2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT type_id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM table_3
) AS x
GROUP BY type_id
```

If there are indexes on the `type_id` column, this query should be able to take advantage of them. And the `UNION` processes smaller tables because it combines after the grouping.

Answer (score 3):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select type_id, count(*)
from ((select type_id from table_1) union all
      (select type_id from table_2) union all
      (select type_id from table_3)
     ) t
group by type_id
```

Comment: Well that saved me some typing! :-)